Authenticating Azure Redis Cache with User Assigned Managed Identity in .NET 8 and C# 12
I am currently working on authenticating with Azure Redis Cache using a User Assigned Managed Identity in .NET 8 and C# 12, instead of the traditional connection string method. I have referred to the Microsoft documentation for implementation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-azure-active-directory-for-authentication
The documentation mentions the following point:
Ensure that your client executes a Redis AUTH command automatically before your Microsoft Entra token expires by using:

User = Object ID of your managed identity or service principal

Password = Microsoft Entra token refreshed periodically

My question is: How can we determine when the token has expired, and how can the client execute a Redis AUTH command automatically before the Microsoft Entra token expires? In this case I don't have access the token and hence it is difficult to know the timeline by when the token will expired.
Any guidance or examples on how to implement this in .NET 8 and C# 12 would be greatly appreciated.
Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation?

I'm using Microsoft.Azure.StackExchangeRedis which is an extension for the StackExchange.Redis client library.
It allows you to configure user-assigned managed identity and maintains refreshing the token it and re-authenticating the connection to ensure uninterrupted communication with the Azure Redis Cache over multiple days.
